Information required on LTCG for mutual fund - New tax regime - India
There is clause mentioned that we can avail 1 lakh exemption for long time captial gain.  Whether this is applicable for new regime also.  I am unable to find any concrete documents supporting or negating this.
Kindly advise. Thanks.
Also let me know if there is any forum / Youtube channel on this topic.  I am a novice.

Read section 112A(2)(i) of Income Tax Act.
